# getting aligned val_loss and train_loss plots for each epoch using WandB rather than separate plots

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, wandb

I have the following code for logging the train and val loss in each epoch using WandB API. I am not sure though why I am not getting val loss and train loss in the same epoch. Any idea how that could be fixed?

```
wandb.log({"train loss": train_epoch_loss,
           "val loss": val_epoch_loss,
           "epoch": epoch})

wandb.log({"train acc": train_epoch_acc,
           "val acc": val_epoch_acc,
           "epoch": epoch})

wandb.log({"best val acc": best_acc, "epoch": epoch})
```

[image]

As you see, val loss vs epochs and train loss vs epochs are two completely separate entities while I would like to have both of them in one plot in WandB.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I work at Weights & Biases, happy to help:

**2 metrics on the same chart**

To plot 2 metrics on the same chart you can click on the pencil icon in the chart to edit it, and then add additional metrics to the y-axis, as shown below.

[image]

**Change default x-axis**

You can also change the X axis to plot against "epoch" instead of the default wandb `step`. If you'd like this behaviour by default you can call `wandb.define_metric` once before you start training and set the x-axis to be `epoch`. See the [define_metric](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/log#customize-axes) docs for more

**Logging step**

One thing to be mindful of is that when you log your validation metrics, you'd like them to be logged at the same step as the train metrics. In this case you can do something like this:

```
metrics = {}

for step, batch in my_data:
  ...
  
  train_loss = ....

  metrics['train_loss'] = train_loss

  if step % val_steps == 0:
    val_loss = ...
  
    metrics['val_loss'] = val_loss
  
    wandb.log(metrics)

  else:
    wandb.log(metrics)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`commit=False` argument](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/python/run#log) in `wandb.log` to store the metric without incrementing the wandb step. And then call `wandb.log()` to increment the step when you need to.

Comment: Ok this works.. But is there really no way of incremental logging and configuring 2 metrics in 1 plot in the code? I do a lot of experiments, and don't want to reconfigure this setting in the workspace manually by hand everytime for every run."

Furthermore, if I define an epoch metric which is configured as x-axis, it also creates a loose epoch plot which is not what I want.